# Take an odd posivitve integer from input and print an odd numbered arrowhead pattern for it

Tags: java

it should be done without printing any other characters. Not even space
for example:
if the sample input is :
3
then the output should be :

```
1
333
1
```

sample input:
5
sample output:

```
1
333
55555
333
1
```

Sample input:
7
Sample output:

```
1
333
55555
7777777
55555
333
1
```

I tried by myself but couldn't get it right and I also searched it up but didn't find any direct answers to it. :(

Comment: _I tried by myself but couldnn't get it right_ -> Please [edit] your question and add the code you tried.

Comment: If you tried yourself, post the code you tried and describe what you get, what problem do you encounter, so that people can help you. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With a little thought, one can use a single loop and the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.4)
for this.

- first, presume `n` is positive and then set the low order bit to correct to the next higher odd value if `n` is even.
- let `m` determine the number and the repetition.  initialize with `-1`.
- iterate from `1 to n`, incrementing m by 2 and printing the increasing lines including the longest line.
- when `n` exceeds that point, decrement m by 2 and continuing printing the rest of the lines.

```
public static void printArrowHead(int n) {
    int m = -1;
    n |= 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.println((i <= n / 2 + 1)
                ? (m + 2 + "").repeat(m += 2)
                : (m - 2 + "").repeat(m -= 2));
    } 
}
```

You may also want to just check to ensure if `n` is positive or already an odd number and take appropriate action.

Also note that the arrowhead becomes distorted when `n` exceeds `9`. This is due to the width of each value on the given line.

Comment: At n  = 19, it looks more like the space shuttle than an arrowhead.